# What opensource NAS firmware are compatible with the D-Link DNS 320?

Tags: nas

I've got a D-Link DNS 320 and the standard firmware is clunky and limited.

What opensource alternatives are there to the standard firmware that can reliably be installed on the DNS 320?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found FFP as a way of opening up the embedded Linux system with SSH access.

http://nas-tweaks.net/40/installation-of-the-fonz-funplug-0-5-for-ch3snas-ch3mnas-dns-323-and-many-more/

Answer (score -1):

Try [FreeNAS](http://www.freenas.org/)...  I am using it at home.  You can also buy some inexpensive solutions with FreeNAS installed on it, so you'll essentially be paying for hardware.

Comment: On the feature chart it states that FreeNas requires 4GB RAM (http://www.freenas.org/features/feature-overview/item/feature-chart?category_id=108). The DNS 320 has only 128MB RAM. Is this an issue?

Comment: Are you trying to install it on you DNS 320?

Comment: Yes, my original question is about what other firmware I can install on my DNS 320. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but that's not what I gathered from your question...  I thought you were looking for an alternative period.

Comment: I thin that is not a correct answer about question. I suggest ALT+F search in sourceforge.net